# Добавить прослушиватель событий для не уникального class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не получается добавить прослушиватель событий для не уникального класса.
К примеру имеется два div.

```
<div class="static"></div>
<div class="static"></div>
```

Оба с одинаковыми классами, с помощью jquery/js мне нужно как-то с ними работать. Обращение к классу *будто ничего не случилось* не помогает.

```
$('.static').bind('click', func);
```

Насколько я понимаю нужно взаимодействовать с `find()` либо `this`
Но я пока не совсем понимаю как, буду благодарен за помощь.

[Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://codepen.io/fbzuqlkp/pen/aXggeJ)

В примере при нажатии в консоль выводятся данные только второго div. Без разницы на какой из них мы нажали, мне же нужно чтобы при нажатии на определённый div выводились именно его данные.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не помогает? Приведи [mcve] в котором видно какой именно код у тебя не работает

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, конкретную проблему, что у Вас не получается,какой результат нужен, а так же Ваши попытки решить проблему.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: _`bind`_? Что за версия? Вроде это устарело сто лет назад.

Comment: jquery 3.3.1, может я использую не так как нужно, но к примеру с jquery при последней попытке не работает addEventListener. Есть какие-либо новые методы для объявления прослушивателя событий? UPD. Увидел ответ Igor с .on(); - Понял, принял, запомнил, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".test").on("click", func);

function func() {
  var $test = $(this);
  var trace = $test.text();
  console.log(trace);
}
```

```css
.test {
  background-color: #969696;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">123</div>
<div class="test">456</div>
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, Игорь!

Comment: @SunsetShimmer Пожалуйста. Успехов!